# Fastlane / Snapshot - how do I keep all debug / console logs?

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I'd like to review the contents of all the debug logs on all the devices I use in my fastlane snapshot ui test?

I'm looking for the debug messages that would also be generated using NSLog etc.

I found this `output_simulator_logs` flag in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. I also set `namespace_log_files` but this just seems to be for the build log.

Although I'm quite happy to achieve this using another fastlane tool or maybe a different tool?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass in `result_bundle: true` should should get some `test_result` bundles. In those bundles, you'll get all the logs that you're looking for. Not that `*.xcactivitylog` files are actually gzip'd text files.